# Find an element from one list and compare it to an element in another list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to compare the contents of two lists-

One list is contains the filename i.e

```
filenamestring = ['a', 'b']
```

The other list contains multiple words and their scores i.e

```
outlist = [('c', 46), ('d',
40), ('e', 37), ('f', 35),('a', 40),('b', 37),('c', 1), ('d',
2), ('e', 3), ('f', 4)]
```

I'm trying to find matching words from the 2 list and if matched correctly add the score with a value of 200

Tried the code below but nothing happened-

```
for letter, number in outlist:
    if word in filenamestring == letter in outlist:
        output[letter] = number + 200

    else:
        output[letter] += number
```

Output:

```
output =  [('c', 47), ('d',42), ('e', 40), ('f', 39),('a', 240),('b', 237)]
```

Comment: Why is it in this weird `["['a", "b']"]` form?

Comment: what is ”word”?

Comment: @coldspeed that was an error in my code, thanks for pointing it out! Made the corrections :)

Comment: why values of a and b increased by 200 while your list contains **Arithmetic** and **mean** ?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar had made an edit there and copy pasted the wrong list, have corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for letter, number in outlist:
if letter in filenamestring: # directly check if letter is in the filenamestring
    output[letter] = number + 200

else:
    output[letter] += number
```

Answer (score 1):

Working Code :

```
    filenamestring = ["b", "a"]

    # The other list contains multiple words and their scores i.e

    outlist = [('c', 46), ('d', 40), ('e', 37), ('f', 35),('a', 40),('b', 37)]

    # I'm trying to find matching words from the 2 list and if matched correctly add the score with a value of 200

    # Tried the code below but nothing happened-
    i = 0
    for letter, number in outlist:

        print(letter + "= " + str(number))

        for word in filenamestring:
            if word  == letter :
                outlist[i] =(letter, number + 20000000)
                break
            else:
                outlist[i] = (letter, number)
        i= i+1

    print(outlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use List Comprehensions:

```
 output = [(i[0], i[1]+200) if i[0] in filenamestring else (i[0],i[1]) for i in outlist]
```